# Unexpected Output involving array values with post and pre-increment

Tags: c, post-increment, pre-increment

Shouldn't the output of following program be -

> 2 3 20

instead it is showing

> 3 2 15

Can anyone explain the reason behind this?

```
#include<stdio.h>
main()
{
    int a[5] = {5,1,15,20,25};
    int i,j,m;
    i = ++a[1];
    j = a[1]++;
    m = a[i++];
    printf("%d %d %d",i,j,m);
}
```

Comment: `i = ++a[1]; j = a[1]++; m = a[i++];` why would anybody do that in real life ? Please, don't ask help for your homeworks.

Comment: It would be helpfull (for you) to add the reasoning why you think `2 3 20` is the correct output.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's garbage homework code of no value.

Answer (score 7):

> 3 2 15

is the correct output.

1. `i` is 3, because `i` became 2 in `i = ++a[1];` for pre-increment and then it got post-incremented in `m = a[i++];`
2. `j`  is 2, because `j = a[1]++;`, no changes afterwards.
3. `m` is 15 because `m = a[i++];` `i` is being post-incremented, the old value of `i` (which is `2`) is used in indexing and the post-increment on `i` is *sequenced* after the evaluation of the `=` statement.

---

Having said that, the recommended signature of `main()` is `int main(int argc, char *argv[])` or at least, `int main(void)`.

Comment: The signature of `main` is completely correct in OPs code. He's using the implicit `int` rule and provides no argument list—thus allowing arbitrary arguments of arbitrary type.

Comment: @FUZxxl `implicit int rule` has been dropped since `C99`. and the signature I mentioned is recommended in the same standard. Just trying to make OP aware of the latest standard. Please note the **recommended** part. Hope it's clear. :-)

Comment: But OP is using the recommended signature, he is just defining his function in a way you don't recommend.

Comment: @FUZxxl Sir, I did not understand your point. And, the recommendation is not by me, it's by the standard. I'm just _repeating_ it. :-)

Comment: What I say is that OP follows the recommendations by the standard. A function defined `main() { ... }` is compatible to both `int main(int, char**)` and `int main(void)`. There is nothing wrong with this way of defining `main`.

Comment: @FUZxxl The fact that gcc yields a warning *return type defaults to int* should tell you that it is not really good style. Sure, it's not plain-dead wrong, but it's discouraged, to say the least.

Comment: @FilipeGonçalves My point is that the reason why you shouldn't write `main() {...}` is wrong. It's not because it's the wrong signature, it's because you are using the implicit `int` rule which you shouldn't.

Comment: @FUZxxl Sir, my native is not English, so I'm not that good at understanding. May I please ask you to point me somewhere where this is explained in detail? I was relying on  §5.1.2.2.1 from `C11`.

Comment: @SouravGhosh C11 does no longer contain the implicit `int` rule, but even C11 says that the definition needs only be *equivalent* to the given one (cf. footnote 10).

Comment: The definition `main() { ... }` declares `main` as a function returning `int`, not `void`. This is called the implicit `int` rule: If you leave out the type in certain contexts, such as in the return type of a function, `int` is assumed.

Comment: @FUZxxl absolutely agree. Sorry about `void` part, I must have mixed up my tabs with some other question. So as the implicit `int` is not supported by the standard any more, we need to be explicit. So, missing `int` is not really recommended, right?

Comment: @SouravGhosh No, implicit `int` is not recommended.

Answer (score 2):

At this point, values of variables are:

```
a = {5,1,15,20,25};
i = uninitialized
j = uninitialized
m = uninitialized
```

Now,

```
i = ++a[1];
```

Gets the value of `a[i]` which is 1, increments it and it becomes 2, and then, it is stored in `i`.

At this point, values of variables are:

```
a = {5,2,15,20,25};
i = 2
j = uninitialized
m = uninitialized
```

Next,

```
j = a[1]++;
```

Gets the value in `a[1]` which is 2 (since it was incremented in the previous statement), stores this value in `j` and then, increments the value stored in `a[1]`.

At this point, values of variables are:

```
a = {5,3,15,20,25};
i = 2
j = 2
m = uninitialized
```

Then,

```
m = a[i++];
```

Gets the value in `a[i]`(`a[2]` since `i` is currently 2) which is 15 and this value is stored in `m`. Then, `i` is incremented.

At this point, values of variables are:

```
a = {5,3,15,20,25};
i = 3
j = 2
m = 15
```

Answer (score 1):

```
3 2 15 is correct

#include<stdio.h>

    main()
    {
    int a[5] = {5,1,15,20,25};
    int i,j,m;
    i = ++a[1];
    j = a[1]++;
    m = a[i++];
    printf("%d %d %d",i,j,m);
    }
```

Now lets go line by line assume i , j , m equals 0 {better to initialize}

from line 3 , `i = ++a[1];`
i = 2 as (++ pre increment , change then use , and a[1] = 1 so , i = 2)

from line 4, `j = a[1]++;`
j = 2 as (++ here is post increment , use then change , a[1] becomes 3 but j is equals to 2)

from line 5, `m = a[i++];`
i = 2 by line 3 , here ++ post increment then i will increment to 3 but a[2] will be used .

> Hence i = 3 , j = 2 , m = 15

Hope you got it ..........